# Decrypt assets (json/png/lua)

Tags: aes, decryption

**Context**

I am trying to decrypt a game for its assets for learning purposes. I have extracted out said assets from the game package, they are in formats of `.json`, `.png` and `.lua`. However, they are encrypted. Inspecting the files in hex view, I noticed something particularly interesting: all of their bytes start with `4448 4741 4d45 53`, which in ascii corresponds to the publisher of the game.

**What I have done**

1. Ran a `strings` command on the game binary to extract all the strings out, one of which should be the decryption key
2. Wrote a python script to try each of the possible keys on these encrypted assets using AES, XXTEA and XOR. The key is validated if the decryption result is a valid json/lua text file.

Usually these two steps alone would find me the key for many other games, but this time to no avail.

What other steps can I do to try to decrypt these assets statically without having to gdb into runtime?

** The link to assets can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7pqhvpsa0ems0q9/AAA8lHrudeix3hJ0Rz2tXPSxa?dl=0

Comment: This really not a security question but a reverse engineering question. I'm also not sure if this is narrow enough to be possibly answered.

Comment: Hop over to http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ and see what requirements they have for questions.

Comment: Would this not also be against the law in several countries? Including, I think, the USA.